# find minima and replace with character string in r

Tags: r, replace

I have a df of oceanographic data with CTD cast/station names in one column and depth in another. It looks something like this

```
is <- data.frame(cast=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), depth=c(10,20,30,5,15,25))
```

Now I would like to find the min and max depth for each cast and replace the value with "surface" and "bottom", respectively. The result should look like this:

```
want <- data.frame(cast=c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), depth=c("surface",20,"bottom","surface",15,"bottom"))
```

I have used aggregate() to find each min/max and tried ifelse() with for loop to replace the values but couldn't make it work. 
Help is much appreciated.
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a classic split/apply/combine approach. However, you should be aware that by introducing strings in a numeric column, the whole column will be converted to character.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(is, is$cast), transform, depth = 
 ifelse(depth == min(depth), "surface", ifelse(depth == max(depth), "bottom", depth))))
#    cast   depth
#a.1    a surface
#a.2    a      20
#a.3    a  bottom
#b.4    b surface
#b.5    b      15
#b.6    b  bottom
```

To avoid type conversion you could consider a different approach, for example:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(is, is$cast), transform, 
             surface = depth == min(depth), 
             bottom  = depth == max(depth)))
#    cast depth surface bottom
#a.1    a    10    TRUE  FALSE
#a.2    a    20   FALSE  FALSE
#a.3    a    30   FALSE   TRUE
#b.4    b     5    TRUE  FALSE
#b.5    b    15   FALSE  FALSE
#b.6    b    25   FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanx @docendo discimus. This worked. I don't have a problem with the conversion to character. I anyways paste cast and depth together to have a unique identifier for each sample.
But could you explain, what `transform` does here?

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one minimum/maximum value per 'cast', another option is using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(is)`), grouped by 'cast', we `order` the 'depth', and create the new column by concatenating 'surface' to the elements of 'depth' except the last one, followed by 'bottom'.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(is)[order(depth), depth1 := c('surface',
                        depth[2:(.N-1)], 'bottom') ,cast]
 is
 #  cast depth  depth1
 #1:    a    10 surface
 #2:    a    20      20
 #3:    a    30  bottom
 #4:    b     5 surface
 #5:    b    15      15
 #6:    b    25  bottom
```

If there are cases where there is only a single observation for 'cast'

```
 setDT(is)[order(depth), depth1 := if(.N > 1) 
    c('surface', depth[2:(.N-1)], 'bottom') else depth ,cast]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tapply`:

```
newdepth <- c(is$cast,is$depth)
newdepth[is==tapply(is$depth,is$cast,max)] <- "bottom"
newdepth[is==tapply(is$depth,is$cast,min)] <- "surface"

want <- is
want$depth <- newdepth[-(1:nrow(want))]
```

But be aware of character values in `want$depth` as @docendo discimus stated.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach using `by`.

```
# First cbind an index
is$index <- 1:nrow(is)

# then find the max and min and return the indeces
foo <- function(x) cbind(min= x$index[which.min(x$depth)], max= x$index[which.max(x$depth)])
gr <- do.call(rbind, by(is, list(is$cast), FUN=  foo))

# subset the extremes and replace the values with your choice. 
is[gr[,1], "depth"] <- "surface"
is[gr[,2], "depth"] <- "bottom"
```